# Set Condition to values php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have arrays and this arrays have values
i need to set Condition to values like that 
my arrays keys variable and Are changing !

And i want check if my custom value exist print somthing...

```
 if ($arraysValue[$keys] ==1) { print "one"; }
 //OR
 if ($arraysValue[$keys] ==3) { print "three"; }
```

Arrays :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [6] => 3
    [9] => 4
    [12] => 5
    [15] => 8
    [18] => 9
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [4] => 2
    [8] => 6
    [12] => 9
)
```

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Unclear `$arraysValue ==1`??

Comment: $arraysValue[$keys] problem is keys are changing!

Comment: Not very clear what you want to do. Are you trying to check if a key exists in an array? Or if a value exists in an array? Or something else?

Comment: yes i want check if my custom value exist print somthing !

Comment: He wants to print digit in alphabet as like `if 1 then script should print one`. For that task you will have to create array for alphabet

Comment: `key` exists or `value`?

Comment: @Yash Parekh `Value`

Comment: If your going to do it the long winded way of using multiple `if`'s then look into using `switch...case...` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go through all your array items and check each one, you can use `foreach`

```
$my_array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
foreach($my_array as $array_index=> $array_value){
   if($array_value == 1)     print "one";
   elseif($array_value== 3)  print "three";
   else                      print "something else";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print the value of each row of your arrays and if the result are only between 1 and 9, you can try something like this :

1/ Create your "alphabet" array where key = the value in letter

```
 $alphabet = array(
    "0" => "zero",
    "1" => "one",
    "2" => "two",
    ...
    "9" => "nine"
)
```

2/ Loop through your arrays and foreach row, you print the value in letter using your alphabet array :

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    print($alphabet[$value]);
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks @Mickael Leger